# Add a region of the screen to a list of images

Tags: c#, winforms, image, list, graphics

I am attempting to add a bitmap image to a `List<Image>` within a timer's tick function. The timer has a 100ms tick, and uses the following code:

```
private void GifTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var bmp = new Bitmap(selection.Width, selection.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb))
    {
        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) graphics.CopyFromScreen(selection.Left, selection.Top, 0, 0, bmp.Size);
        images.Add(bmp); //Adds null values apparently.
    }
}
```

I ran some breakpoint debugging and found that `bmp` is not null, and has a correct width and height based on the selection. I am using the same code elsewhere for some other purpose, and it works as intended. But when this bitmap is added to my list, it returns null.

Am I missing something here? the list is initialized as a `new List<Image>();` in my constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `using` to dispose your bitmap automatically:

```
var bmp = new Bitmap(selection.Width, selection.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) 
  graphics.CopyFromScreen(selection.Left, selection.Top, 0, 0, bmp.Size);
images.Add(bmp);
```